# WPF ItemsControl - Command on ViewModel not firing from within ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, itemscontrol

I'm using M-V-VM and have a command on my ViewModel called 'EntitySelectedCommand'.

I've trying to get all the Items in an ItemsControl to fire this command, however it's not working.

I think it's because each items 'datacontext' is the individual object the item is bound to, rather than the ViewModel?

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Cheers,

Andy

```
<ItemsControl  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=LinkedSuppliers}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <Controls:EntityLabel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding Name}" CurrentEntity="{Binding }" EntitySelected="{Binding EntitySelectedCommand}" ></Controls:EntityLabel>                
            <StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your suspicion is correct. You have a couple of options:

1. Expose an `EntitySelectedCommand` from your child view model as well (ie. each `Supplier` would have this property, too).
2. Change your binding to use a `RelativeSource` to reach out and use the `DataContext` of the parent `ItemsControl`.

Comment: Excellent, many thanks - got it working with RelativeSource as you suggested ...

EntitySelected="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}, Path=DataContext.EntitySelectedCommand}"

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [MVVM Toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=WPF%20Model-View-ViewModel%20Toolkit)... It has this idea of a command refrence which you can use!

Create a CommandRefrece as a resource and then just use the StaticResource markup extension...

```
<c:CommandRefrence x:Key="EntitySelectedCommandRef" Command="{Binding EntitySelectedCommand}" />
```

and then later you can use

```
...Command="{StaticResource EntitySelectedCommandRef}" ...
```